# Why search in Google Calendar not finding a reminder?

Tags: google-calendar

I have a reminder in September for a Dermatologist appointment. I didn't know what day it is in so I used search and entered Dermatologist and it didn't find it. I had to click on each day until I found it. I copied the word and pasted it in search and did a search again and it didn't find it.

What's wrong with the calendar search? It also doesn't work for partial words. If I enter 'derm', it doesn't find anything.
Not very useful when it's limited and doesn't function as expected.